# How to selectively zoom x and/or y in d3.js -- dynamically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have [a small JavaScript graphing/histogramming library](http://i3d3.org) which allows zooming/panning in either X or Y directions, or both, as declared when the plot is created.  A simplified example is in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShBQw/).

What I want to do instead is to allow the zoom behavior to change when, e.g., the shift key is pressed.

The core of the zoom logic in my example currently looks like this:

```
 function draw() {
     // handle rendering of plot
 }

 // zoom behavior:
 var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom();
 zoom.x(xscale);
 //zoom.y(yscale);   <-- add this in if y-scrolling is to be allowed

 zoom.on("zoom", draw);

 // Restrict zoom action to display box (non-axis part) only:
 svg.append("svg:rect")
     .attr("class", "pane")
     .attr("width", w - (padding_left + padding_right))
     .attr("height", h - (padding_top + padding_bottom))
     .attr("cursor", "move")
     .attr("fill", "none")
     .attr("pointer-events", "all")
     .attr("x", padding_left)
     .attr("y", padding_top)
     .call(zoom);

 function keydown() {
     if(d3.event.shiftKey) {
         // turn on y-zoom behavior, turn off x...
     }
 }

 function keyup() {
     // revert to old behavior
 }

 d3.select("body").on("keydown", keydown);
 d3.select("body").on("keyup", keyup);
```

I can turn on X or Y zooming selectively when the plot is set up; but I want to do this intermittently, when the shift key is pressed, i.e. in `keydown` and `keyup`.  Since the zoom behavior is wired in to my "pane" div once, it's not clear to me how to make this dynamic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to handle this in your `zoom` function. That is, instead of modifying what events are generated, you just modify how to handle them. So if x zoom is enabled, you only specify the x scale. The code would look something like this.

```
var zoom = d3.behaviour.zoom().on("zoom", onZoom);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").call(zoom);

function onZoom() {
  if(x_zoom) {
    svg.attr("transform", "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ", 1)");
  }
  else if(y_zoom) {
    svg.attr("transform", "scale(1, " + d3.event.scale + ")");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- I'm not totally following you, though.  If you look at the fiddle I linked to, my `draw` function doesn't explicitly reference the transformation details; it just uses the `xscale` and `yscale` objects which are presumably changed by the zoom event...?  What change is needed to be able to apply the transformations in a more selective way?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread -- thought you were talking about panning. Now I'm not sure what you mean anymore -- do you want to change the scales used to draw the chart, or actually zoom into the SVG?

Comment: I want to both zoom and pan, but zoom in X or Y directions (or both) selectively, based on shift key pressed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by zoom in x/y direction. If you transformed the SVG this way, it would looked stretched out.

Comment: Stretched out is fine - that is what I want as default behavior (expanding along the X axis).  But I want the user to be able to turn on Y "expansion" as well / instead.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a plugin that modifies d3's default zoom behavior to allow for this:

[image]

https://github.com/mathisonian/d3-multiaxis-zoom

Answer (score 2):

I will just add something in Lars Kotthoff answer.

It will be much better if we add translation as well
i.e.

```
//For X-Zoom
svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + " ,1)");
//For Y-Zoom
svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(1, " + d3.event.scale + ")");
```

This solution will work even if your drawing svg is in different container and scale svg is in different container.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if you call `zoom.x` or `.y` again with a new `d3.scale.linear()` argument, it will disable that axis's pan/zoom behavior, and if you call it again with the original `xscale` or `yscale`, it will reenable it.

However, one problem I ran into is that, unlike `mouseover` events, I could not tie `keydown` and `keyup` events to an individual `div` or `svg`; they are fired for the page as a whole (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126232/d3-intercepting-keydown-events-over-specific-elements)).  This meant that, in order to support multiple graphs in [i3d3](http://i3d3.org), I had to save separate `zoom` and `scale` behaviors for each plot; otherwise, only the last plot on the page would have the correct behavior.

I'll keep this question unanswered for a while to see if other people have additional suggestions.