# d3: intercepting keydown events over specific elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to identify key press events which occur over specific D3 elements.  The following snippet ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eigenhombre/4KKdT/) here) correctly identifies mousing over individual divs, and global key press events, but does not seem to fire the div-specific key press handler (tested only on Chrome so far).  What is the simplest way to either:

1. identify which `div`/`svg` the cursor is over, or
2. attach a key handler to a specific `div`/`svg`

?

```
_.each(_.range(2), function (i) {
    var svg = d3.select("#plot" + i).append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .on("mouseover", function () { console.log("mouseover", i); })
        .on("keydown", function () { console.log("div key", i); });
});

d3.select("body").on("keydown", function () { console.log("global key"); });
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

As a followup, I suppose I could capture the div ID in the mouseover handler and use that to identify the appropriate div in the global keydown event -- but I'm curious if there is a more elegant or idiomatic solution.

Comment: You can use [`elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) to get the element, `d3.select` it and call functions on it.

Comment: That might get a bit weird if there are text labels over the rectangles. elementFromPoint only grabs the topmost element in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***D'oh. Your edit had exactly this solution. Yup, that's probably the best way to handle it. ***

You might need to use the mouseover handler to keep track of the element that is currently focused, and then use the page listener to delegate the event to that node.

something like this:

```
var focused = null;
svg.append("rect").on("mouseover", function () { focused = this; })
```

And then in your page-handler:

```
d3.select("body").on("keydown", function () { d3.select(focused); /* then do something with it here */ });
```

Comment: Thanks, I did wind up doing something like this.  I'll keep this open for awhile  to see if anyone else chimes in.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use d3.event.stopPropagation() to keep events from bubbling up to the body.